# Spring Security Config not skipping authentication for certain URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I've tried a dozen different configurations but I cannot get the Spring Security to do the use-case I am attempting. 
I want the security to do the following

1. Use Basic Authentication on specified URLs (/api/service/**)
2. Do not validate Basic Auth if sent with all other URL's

Currently whenever I send a request to any URL outside of /api/service/** it works fine HOWEVER if I send a Basic Auth token with those it then tried to authenticate it. I don't want the token to be completely ignored for all other URL's though. Is there a way to do that?

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/service/**").hasRole("ROLE_SERVICE")
        .and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new RestAccessDeniedHandler())
        .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

I've also tried adding `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**").anonymous()` and `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("**").permitAll()` but neither of those have done the trick. I had also tried removing the .httpBasic() but then no validation takes place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using: Spring Security 3.2.9.RELEASE and Spring MVC 3.2.13.RELEASE.

Comment: so when you send a request with auth headers to an url that does not require auth, it tries to authenticate anyways?

Comment: Correct, I know that sounds like a strange use case, but most of the API's are completely open so I only want to be able to authenticate on certain ones since I cannot control if other's will add different Authentications in the header.
Edit: If I provide an invalid basic auth token is when it is bad. If I provide a basic auth token that would validate properly for /api/service/** into the other API's it works (as it is authenticating through the Spring Security).

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/api/service/**").hasRole("ROLE_SERVICE")
         .anyRequest().permitAll()
```

Comment: With this the basic auth is never validated so even for the /api/services/** calls.

Comment: The order of permission assign matters. Are you sure you give `.anyRequest().permitAll()` only after `.antMatchers("/api/service/**").hasRole("ROLE_SERVICE")`

Comment: Also did you have `/api/service/**` or `/api/services/**`. Your question has only `service`, in comment you mentions `services`